# Is multi-test II device the real deal for determining a person's allergies?

Tags: allergy, medical-device, dizziness, allergen

I have been experiencing chronic dizziness - most of the time, lightheadedness and seldomly with vertigo attacks since July 2015. I have already had my ear, eye, brain (mri), heart (2d echo, holter monitor, ultrasound at my neck), anemia, and many other blood tests to no avail.

Recently, I learned from my cousin that he was also experiencing dizziness whenever he's sitting down, and it fades once he stands up. When he went to check up his eye with an opthalmologist, the doctor said there is a lump inside the eye and turns out he is allergic to pollen. He drank antihistamine and became well.

So I went to see an allergologist and she claims that she will be using an imported test kit using real allergens but it costs too much.

Is the equipment the real deal?
https://www.adclinic.com/skin-testing-for-allergies/#.Vt2Cfpx97WL